# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, when calling Standard Library DLL

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-standard-2.0, regedit, xaf

I have the following stack with an XAF Winforms, Entity Framework Project;

```
Framework 4.72 exe which references
Framework 4.7.2 library1 which references
.Net Standard 2.0 library2 which references
.Net Standard 2.0 library3
```

A call down the stack to a method in library3 produces an exception.

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80070002
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=3.1.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I was able to replicate the problem in a Framework 4.7.2 unit test that called Library2 directly and to solve that.

To solve the problem in the unit test I used BindingRedirectGenerator to generate the runtime section of the unit test app.config as per the answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60540720/how-do-i-expose-a-netstandard2-0-library-with-com-for-use-in-vb6)

However this does not work when I use the generated section for the application app.config

[Update]

I think the issue is that Library3 calls a framework library... investigating.

Comment: set "AutoGenerateBindingRedirects" to true in cproj file. Why are you not updating to latest version 3.1.12?

Comment: open the generated **project.assets.json** in obj folder and look which lib uses 3.1.9.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a form of the question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60540720/how-do-i-expose-a-netstandard2-0-library-with-com-for-use-in-vb6)
Yet even after having asked the question before I still got caught.
The solution was to create a unit test project with a dialog box, then, at the message box, run BindingRedirectGenerator to make the app.config

I am up for advice on whether this question is useful (since the problem was encountered a different way) or should be closed.

The issue in not getting the technique working for the .exe appears to be a new problem to do with calling a framework library from a standard library.

Comment: Here is the follow up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66270632/nu1701-can-i-reference-a-winforms-framework-library-from-a-standard-2-0-library